# Token gets refreshed before HTTP request but new token isn't being sent with request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using angular2 and ionic 2s frameworks storage. I make several calls to my API and before them I call the `refresh()` function to refresh the token if need be.

An example of the problem: A user starts typing "AB" in the search bar and the token expires. The User now types "C", `refresh()` gets called but a token is not sent with the request but if a user presses "D" right after a token is provided so my guess is that a call to the API is being made after the token has been removed from storage but before its being saved

```
get(): Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.get('token_id').then(token_id => {
    this.token_id = token_id;
  });
}

set(token_id) {
  this.storage.set('token_id', token_id);
}

refresh(): Observable <any> {

  let obs = Observable.fromPromise(this.get())
    .filter(() => this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token_id))
    .flatMap(() =>  this.authHttp.get('http://api.app/api/refresh?token_id=' + this.token_id));
  obs.subscribe((response: Response) => {
    this.token_id = response.json().token_id;
    this.set(this.token_id);
  }, (error: Response) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  return obs;
}
```

service that makes the call that calls refresh()

```
search(key): Observable<any> {

  this.userService.refresh();

  return this.authHttp.get('http://' + keyword)
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      },
    (error: Error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
    );
}
```

component that subscribes to search() call

```
onSearch(event)
{
  let key = event.target.value;

  this.searchService.search(key)
    .subscribe(
      (prods: SearchInterface[]) => this.prods = prods,
      (error: Response) => {
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: When search api is called if the token is expired then server will be responding with 401 or 403 error code. So if you are receiving that error on search api call after calling the refresh token just call the same search api again...

Answer (score 0):

When the login is success you need to save the token in localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("token", this.token);
```

you can get token with

```
localStorage.getItem("token")
```

Comment: It is being saved in the storage in response